# multiple plots in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am working on a task to develop an interactive dashboard using Shiny, and I managed to do it however when I merged the code to display 3 plots, 2 of them appeared but the 3rd one gave me an error:

> [: subscript out of bounds   [No stack trace available]

here is my code

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(    

  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Age ranges according to program"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "MBA", label = "MBA"),
      actionButton(inputId = "MSLOD", label = "MSLOD"),
      actionButton(inputId = "MSQBE", label = "MSQBE"),
      selectInput("Program", "Program:",  choices=colnames(Majoraccordingtogender)),
      selectInput("Program", "Position:", choices=colnames(Majorsaccordingtoposition))



    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(

      column(6,plotOutput("hist")), 
      column(8,plotOutput("Plot")),
      column(10,plotOutput("Plot1"))





      )

    )

  )
)




server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(data = Majorsaccordingtoage[1,1:4])

  observeEvent(input$MBA, { rv$data <- Majorsaccordingtoage[1,1:4] })
  observeEvent(input$MSLOD, { rv$data <- Majorsaccordingtoage[2,1:4] })
  observeEvent(input$MSQBE, { rv$data <- Majorsaccordingtoage[3,1:4] })

  output$hist <- renderPlot({ 

    barplot(rv$data, 
            main=input$radio,
            ylab="Number employees",
            xlab="Ages Range",col=rainbow(4))
  })
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    pct <- round(as.numeric(Majoraccordingtogender[,input$Program])/sum(as.numeric(Majoraccordingtogender[,input$Program]))*100)
    lbls <- paste(pct) 
    lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") 

    pie(Majoraccordingtogender[,input$Program], 
        main=input$Program,
        col=rainbow(2),
        labels = lbls)
    legend("topright", c("Male", "Female"), cex=0.8,fill=rainbow(length(Majoraccordingtogender[,input$Program])))
  })
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({


    barplot(Majorsaccordingtoposition[,input$Program], 
            main=input$Program,col=rainbow(3),xlab = "Programs"
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and my data sets looks like this

Majorsaccordingtoage

```
       0-25 25-30  30-40   40-65
MBA     5   133     258    106
MSLOD   4   59      60     28
MSQBE   2   34      64     28
```

Majorsaccordingtoposition

```
    DIRECTOR    MANAGER OFFICER NOT EMPLOYEE    NOT MENTIONED
MBA    10       67     172       104             10
MSLOD   1       17     57       22               6
MSQBE   0       15      39      13               3
```

Majoraccordingtogender

```
       MBA  MSLOD  MSQBE
Male    281   79    44
Female  221   72    84
```

please note all data types are a matrix.

thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Just a misplaced comma.

`Majorsaccordingtoposition[,input$Program]` to `Majorsaccordingtoposition[input$Program,]`

```
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({


    barplot(Majorsaccordingtoposition[input$Program,], 
            main=input$Program,col=rainbow(3),xlab = "Programs"
    )
  })
```

Comment: Update: Although this answer does add the plot it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

thank for your help , i found the answer that

```
output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({


    barplot(Majorsaccordingtoposition[,input$Program], 
            main=input$Program,col=rainbow(3),xlab = "Programs"
    )
  })
```

in main= inpu$program is the issue , so i had to change the world "program" in 
ui and server to any otherword

```
  selectInput("Program", "Position:", choices=colnames(Majorsaccordingtoposition))
```

because its similar to the below code

```
selectInput("Program", "Program:",  choices=colnames(Majoraccordingtogender))
```